# Graph is not showing up in the webpage using php and html

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get a Graph from mySQL database, but somehow it doesn't show a graph on my webpage.

This is the graph.html file, which should be showing the graph on the webpage.

```
<h1>Graphs</h1>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        var jsonData = null;

        var json = $.ajax({
          url: "data.php", // make this url point to the data file
          dataType: "json",
          async: false,
          success: (
        function(data) {
            jsonData = data;
        })
        }).responseText;

        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);


        // Create and draw the visualization.
      var chart= new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                        width: 500, height: 400,
                        vAxis: {maxValue: 10}}
                );
      }

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the browser I get an error saying:
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $.ajax is not a function` and
`Error: Could not establish connection. receiving end does not exist.`

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Edit:

In the head I've changed: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to     `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"></script>`, I tought i used a slim version of jquery, so i've chand the head of the html file, but it still doesn't work.

I tried downloading jquery using `npm install jquery`, but that doesn't do anything for either.

Most of my code for the html page is from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example.
So i'm kind of lost where to look for errors.

Comment: Looks like you didn't load jQuery properly. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Also, if you can ensure that PHP is not related, please remove the irrelevant parts from your question

Comment: Check the Network tool in the browser while you're loading the page, to see if there's any failure while trying to download the jquery file

Comment: @NicoHaase I cannot ensure that that PHP i completely correct. I tried to search online to  see how to fix the error and the only things what came up were that I could have used a slim version of Jquery (which isn't the case) or that it is caused by some other script taking $ (but I don't have another script having such a function)

Comment: @ADyson I do get a error in the network tool, it is a 404 error in HTML file favicon.ico.

Comment: That 404 error about the Favicon looks completely unrelated to me. Please remove the irrelevant parts from your question, and add your attempts to resolve the remaining problem

Comment: @NicoHaase I took the AJAX API from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example., so I'm kind of lost to see wehere the problem could be. Google should have an up to date script, so I don't now where to look for.

Comment: Based on the google link, why did you add the ajax `success` function? Remove that, and also restore the `var jsonData = $.ajax` (remove the one set to null before that point), because the ajax fetches the `responseText`. To the `url:`, I used their `getData.php` example, though if you renamed your file to `data.php`, then keep this as-is, but ensure your local file name matches. **With those changes, the line graph worked for me**. I did see a promise error, because I had the `data.php` url reference from your example, and I needed the `getData.php` to match what I have from google's example.